# Write a loop for the columns for nC2 iteration for a large dataframe in r?

Tags: r

```
  Patient  Date      c1   c2   c3   c4   c5      c6       c7
1: xyz    01-AUG-14  60  7.0   12  9.0  0.00     34       6.700
2: pqr    05-SEP-14  65  9.0   34 11.0  0.76     12       5.180
3: asd    08-AUG-14  57  6.0   45 12.0  0.00     12       4.830
4: we     10-JUL-14  68 20.0   78 13.0  0.00     45       3.560
5: zxc    14-OCT-14  23   0   11  34.6  0.00     67
```

The above is my dataframe format and i want to write a loop in such a way that for each iteration i need subset of data like

c1   c2
  60   7.0
  65   9.0
  57    6.0
  68   20.0
  23   0
I mean I want to access columns c1&c2, c1&c3, c1&c4, c1&c5, c2&c3, c2&c4, c2&c5, c3&c4, c3&c5,c4&c5

I'm out of idea to write a loop for this..

Comment: Why you are not taking 57 6.0 ?

Comment: yes have to take 57 6.0 only..

Comment: i just showed the format how do i get the subset

Answer (score 1):

If we need the output in a `list` (assuming the dataset is `data.table`), subset the columns with column name pattern "c" followed by number, and use `combn`

```
nm1 <- grep("c\\d+", names(d1), value = TRUE)
lst <- combn(d1[, ..nm1], 2, FUN = list)
lst[[1]]
#   c1 c2
#1: 60  7
#2: 65  9
#3: 57  6
#4: 68 20
#5: 23  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you want all combination of columns `c1, c2, ...etc` to be passed to function/loop and along with that you want to have access to `Patient` and `Date` column too.

To demonstrate the logic, a simple `print` function has been created to combine each group.

```
# Function to receive each group of combinations along with Patient & Date
myprint <- function(x,Patient,Date){
  print(cbind.data.frame(Patient,Date,x))
}

The data:
df1 <- read.table(text = "Patient  Date  c1 c2 c3 c4  c5  c6  c7
1: xyz    01-AUG-14  60  7.0   12  9.0  0.00     34       6.700
2: pqr    05-SEP-14  65  9.0   34 11.0  0.76     12       5.180
3: asd    08-AUG-14  57  6.0   45 12.0  0.00     12       4.830
4: we     10-JUL-14  68 20.0   78 13.0  0.00     45       3.560
5: zxc    14-OCT-14  23   0   11  34.6  0.00     67       3.0", 
header = TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The `combn` function can be used generate desired output:

```
>combn(df1[,3:ncol(df1)], 2, myprint, simplify = FALSE, Patient = df1[,1], Date = df1[,2])
#   Patient      Date c1 c2
#1:     xyz 01-AUG-14 60  7
#2:     pqr 05-SEP-14 65  9
#3:     asd 08-AUG-14 57  6
#4:      we 10-JUL-14 68 20
#5:     zxc 14-OCT-14 23  0
#   Patient      Date c1 c3
#1:     xyz 01-AUG-14 60 12
#2:     pqr 05-SEP-14 65 34
#3:     asd 08-AUG-14 57 45
#4:      we 10-JUL-14 68 78
#5:     zxc 14-OCT-14 23 11
#   Patient      Date c1   c4
#1:     xyz 01-AUG-14 60  9.0
#2:     pqr 05-SEP-14 65 11.0
#3:     asd 08-AUG-14 57 12.0
#4:      we 10-JUL-14 68 13.0
#5:     zxc 14-OCT-14 23 34.6
...............
................
```

Comment: Error in matrix(r, nrow = len.r, ncol = count) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Comment: @Asha At what step you got that error? You said you got output as well as error? Did you get the output as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @Asha I have modified my answer to add `simplify = FALSE`. Probably final return value of that function was causing problem at your end.

Comment: @Asha Cool. You can [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if happy with answer.